# NullPointerException in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I write this code in kotlin activity

```
var tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_kotlin) as TextView
```

It always crashes with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

And I find when I convert my Java codes to kotlin codes,the auto converter always does like this:

```
private var btn: Button? = null
```

And when I use the reference, I have to put a !! behind it which make the codes really ugly.So what is the correct way binding UI in kotlin android?

The completed code:

```
class JavaToKotlinActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv) as TextView
    private var btn: Button? = null
    private var et: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_to_kotlin)
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn) as Button
        et = findViewById(R.id.et) as EditText
        btn!!.setOnClickListener { tv.text = "haha" }
        et!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

And the error messages :

```
06-09 14:25:38.574 9770-9770/com.mimi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: com.mimi, PID: 9770
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mimi/com.mimi.Views.JavaToKotlinActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2643)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5799)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:116)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:199)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                            at com.mimi.Views.JavaToKotlinActivity.<init>(JavaToKotlinActivity.kt:20)
                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2643) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5799) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
```

Comment: can you attach complete class code here?

Comment: you can't call `findViewById` before onActivityCreated. So you can't use it in static initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must bind your views after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_to_kotlin)`

if you don't want use nullable type:

```
private lateinit var tv: TextView
```

and in `initView()`

```
tv = findViewById(R.id.tv) as TextView
```

And don't forget about screen rotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in your Gradle file

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

you can directly use the View id

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top TextView from your code,

private var tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv) as TextView

and do should do like this.

```
class JavaToKotlinActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var tv: TextView? = null
    private var btn: Button? = null
    private var et: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_to_kotlin)
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn) as Button
        et = findViewById(R.id.et) as EditText
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv) as TextView

        btn?.setOnClickListener{
            tv?.text = "haha"
        }

        et?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```